# I am trying to write SQL that will let me select 2 columns, transform 1 into 2 and count them

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on a project Where I want to use SQL to select the creation date, creation user and count how many unique instances. The problem is I am change the creation date into 2 separate fields of YEAR and MONTH taking my total columns from 3 to 4 and my SQL results are never correct.

Currenly using MySQL database via MySQL Workbench

Below is the SQL i wrote

```
SELECT YEAR(Create_Date) AS Year, MONTHNAME(Create_Date) AS Month, Created_By, count(YEAR(Create_Date))AS Total
             FROM appointments 
             GROUP BY Create_Date, Created_By, MONTHNAME(Create_Date), YEAR(Create_Date);
```

So far it doesn't return all the "Created_By" user names, And isn't Grouping the Years or Months for the Count. Pictured Below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPWjJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is grouping by Create_Date instead of Year and Month. You need to include the Created_By column in the GROUP BY clause to get the count of unique instances per user like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(Create_Date) AS Year, MONTHNAME(Create_Date) AS Month, Created_By, COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(YEAR(Create_Date), '-', MONTH(Create_Date))) AS Total
FROM appointments 
GROUP BY Year, Month, Created_By;
```

I hope this would work

Answer (score 0):

generally your group by has to be exactly like your select clause:

```
SELECT YEAR(Create_Date) AS Year, MONTHNAME(Create_Date) AS Month, Created_By, count(YEAR(Create_Date))AS Total
             FROM appointments 
             GROUP BY YEAR(Create_Date), MONTHNAME(Create_Date), Created_By;
```